# Fitting GLM (family = inverse.gaussian) on simulated AR(1)-data

Tags: generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, autoregressive, inverse-gaussian-distribution

I am encountering quite an annoying and to me incomprehensible problem, and I hope some of you can help me. I am trying to estimate the autoregression (influence of previous measurements of variable X on current measurement of X) for 4 groups that have a positively skewed distribution to various degrees. The theory is that more positively skewed distributions have less variance, and since the relationship between 2 variables depends on the amount of shared variance, positively skewed distributions have a smaller autoregression that more normally distributed variables.

I use simulations to investigate this, and generate data as follows: I simulate data for n people with tp time points. I use a fixed autoregressive parameter, phi (at .3 so we have a stationary process). To generate positively skewed distributions I use a chi-square distributed error. Individuals differ in the degrees of freedom that is used for the chi2 distributed errors. In other words, degrees of freedom is a level 2 variable (and is in itself chi2(1)-distributed). Individuals with a very low df get a very skewed distribution whereas individuals with a higher df get a more normal distribution.

```
for(i in 1:n) { # Loop over persons.

chi[i, 1] <- rchisq(1, df[i]) # Set initial value.

  for(t in 2:(tp + burn)) { # Loop over time points. 

    chi[i, t] <- phi[i] * chi[i, t - 1] + # Autoregressive effect.
     rchisq(1, df[i]) # Chi-square distributed error.

    } # End loop over time points.
} # End loop over persons.
```

Now that I have the outcome variable generated, I put it in long format, I create a lagged predictor, and I person mean center the predictor (or group mean center, or cluster mean center, all the same). I call this lagged and centered predictor chi.pred. I make the subgroups based on the degrees of freedom of individuals. The 25% with a lowest df goes in subgroup 1, 26% - 50% in subgroup 2, etc.

The problem is this: fitting a multilevel (i.e. mixed or random effects model) autoregressive(1) model with family = inverse.gaussian and link = 'identity', using glmer() from the lme4 package gives me quite a lot of warnings. E.g. "degenerate Hessian", "large eigen value/ratio", "failed to converge with max|grad", etc.. I just don't get why.

The model I fit are

```
# Random intercept, but fixed slope with subgroups as level 2 predictor of slope. 
lmer(chi ~ chi.pred + chi.pred:factor(sub.df.noise) + (1|id), data = sim.data, control = lmerControl(optimizer = 'bobyqa')) 

# Random intercept and slope. 
lmer(chi ~ chi.pred + (1 + chi.pred|id), data = sim.data, control = lmerControl(optimizer = 'bobyqa'))
```

The reason I use inverse gaussian is because it is said to work better on skewed data.

Does anybody have any clue why I can't fit the models? I have tried increasing sample size and time points, different optimizers, I have double-double-double checked if lagging and centering the data is correct, increased the number of iterations, added some noise to the subgroups (since otherwise they are 1 on 1 related to degree of freedom) etc.